# Unable to embed google plus posts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-plus

I am trying to embed google plus posts in my application.
I have loaded **platform.js** file in header

```
<script>
  window.___gcfg = {
    lang: 'en-US',
    parsetags: 'onload'
  };
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>
</script>
<script>
  function renderWidget() {
    gapi.post.render("widget-div", {'href' : 'https://plus.google.com/109813896768294978296/posts/hdbPtrsqMXQ'} );
  }
</script>
```

In html page

```
<a href="#" onClick="renderWidget();">Render the embedded post</a>
<div id="widget-div"></div>
```

When I clicked on the link, it shows nothing. Is there anything to be added. Here is the reference i followed https://developers.google.com/+/web/embedded-post

Comment: It's working fine for me in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rmvv67wy/).

Answer (score 1):

You might be opening `HTML` file directly in browser, which could be problem in some browser(s) (i.e. In Google Chrome. You can verify the issue [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/46)).

Try running it using a local-server(XAMPP maybe) so the `URL` will look similar to `http://localhost/yourpath/test.html`

Hope this helps!!